# JavaScript multiple simultaneous replace

Tags: javascript, string, replace

What is the simplest way in JS to replace multiple things in string at once (without them interfering)? Like

```
"tar pit".replaceArray(['tar', 'pit'], ['capitol', 'house']);
```

...so it produces "capitol house", not "cahouseol house"?

Comment: the simplest answer: **regex**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var replaceArray = function(str, from, to) {
   var obj = {}, regex;
   from.forEach(function(item, idx){obj[item] = to[idx];});

   regex = new RegExp('(' + from.join('|') + ')', 'g');
   return str.replace(regex, function(match){return obj[match]});
}

replaceArray("tar pit", ["tar", "pit"], ["capitol", "house"]);
```

Comment: +1 for much better code than mine, cant see my code over you :).

Answer (score 2):

how about this -

```
function replaceArray(text, toBeReplacedArray, replacementArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toBeReplacedArray.length; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp(toBeReplacedArray[i], 'g');
        text = text.replace(re, '__' + i + '__');

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < replacementArray.length; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp('__' + i + '__', 'g');
        text = text.replace(re, replacementArray[i]);
    }
    return text;
}

replaceArray("tar pit", ['tar', 'pit'], ['capitol', 'house']);
```